# I can't set XZP File Viewer as deflaut for .xzp

Tags: windows-7, file-association, default-settings

I am trying to set my XZP File Viewer as the default program for all .xzp files.
However any time I attempt to set it as default, it refuses to actually choose the program.
Here are some pictures to give a better idea of what I mean.

### [The File Itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrSZI.png)

### [Program Properties, Location & File Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gE3O5.png)

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.
Just so you know, I have tried just about every single way and google attempt to doing this.
I just can't get it done....

Comment: could you provide some detail on 'every single way and google attempt to doing this.' you could place it below the 'every single way and google attempt to doing this.' line, thanks

Comment: Try [OpenWithAdd](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/openwithadd.htm) to add/register the program once, and then repeat the file association.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it's pointing to a library and not an exe. I recommend you to make a new shortcut of the program itself:

1. Right click > propierties.
2. Copy the path.
3. Add the path when you are trying to add the default application.